# how to get id of new added data in reducer

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I am dispatching a action which create data in database and also add that data in reducer. My question is how can I get id of just added data? I want to show id to the user.

```
//on button click this method dispatch a action
create(){
 this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.CreateData({test:"hello"}));
 this.idOfCreatedData = ""; //dont know how
 //normally i retrieve data from store through 'selectors' like
 this.alldata= this.store.select(fromStore.getAllData);
}
```

The data is created in store like

id:{
  test:"hello"
}

The reducer have these standard selector.

```
export function reducer():{ //just normal reducer
   switch(){
     case...
   }
}

export const getDataEntities= (state: MyState) => state.entities;
export const getDataLoading = (state: MyState) => state.loading;
export const getDataLoaded = (state: MyState) => state.loaded;
// here also, how to export just added data
```

Looks pretty same like https://github.com/UltimateAngular/ngrx-store-effects-app/blob/15-create-pizza/src/products/store/reducers/pizzas.reducer.ts 
and https://github.com/UltimateAngular/ngrx-store-effects-app/blob/15-create-pizza/src/products/store/selectors/pizzas.selectors.ts

What I am trying to achieve is, when data is added to database and in mystate, I want to print on HTML that

```
your new data entry has been added and id for this entry is {{idOfCreatedData}}
```

Comment: what I could do is:
first get all the data (all the entities) and now after adding new data get again all the data and compare them. But its not a good solution

Comment: You can have lastUpdatedData key in your state. update this key with the new data whenever you are adding the data to the store. Create a selector function which returns the lastUpdatedData from the state

Comment: @Indragith ja is also a way to do this. Thanks. Will take this way

Answer (score 0):

After you dispatched an action an the reducer added your values to the store you have to select the data from the store

```
this.store.select(yourSelectorFunction).subscribe()
```

I think the official example app of ngrx is a better resource:
https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/projects/example-app

Comment: thats is my question: how this  'yourSelectorFunction' will give me just freshly added data (or data id). 
As soon as I will dispatch action to add data, my state don't know which data is added recently.

Comment: your store automatically emits a new state after your state has changed, you can prove it for your whole state with `this.store.select().subscribe`, if you only want a emission for a slice of your state, you have to write a selector function to get this pieces of your state.